# How i can change the value of page from query string in Web api asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

When I use route

`https://localhost:5001/api/v1/product?page=20`

It return the result with page=10

```
{
     "page":10,
     "limit":1
}
```

This doesn't change the page. How I can change the page value?
Here is my controller

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("{page?}")]
        public ActionResult<ProductDTO> Get(int? page) {
            //lets say we wanted to validate id
            int newPage= page ?? 10;
            var result = _db.Product.ToList();
           
           
            ProductDTO productDTO = new ProductDTO(result,newPage, 1, 1);
            return new ActionResult<ProductDTO>(productDTO);
        }
```

And my code ProductDTO is

```
 public class ProductDTO {
        public virtual ICollection<Product> data { get; set; }
        public int? page { get; set; }
        public int? limit { get; set; }
        public int? skip { get; set; }
        public ProductDTO(List<Blog> result) {
        }
        public ProductDTO(ICollection<Product> Data,int? Page,int? Limit, int? Skip) {
            data = Data;
            page = Page;
            limit = Limit;
            skip=Skip;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `page ?? 10` should ring a bell...

Comment: @JHBonarius can you explain for me please?